# Unable to install spree gem using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I am trying to install `spree` and its extension `spree_static_content`. I want `spree 3.1.0 beta` because thats the dependency for `spree_static_content`. But when I try to run bundle install, i get

`Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree.git`

but its stuck there. here is my gemfile

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '~> 3.1.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '~> 3.1.0.beta'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '~> 3.1.0.beta'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: 'master'
```

I am able to install other versions of spree by mentioning just the version, 
for eg.
 `gem 'spree' , '~> 3.0.7'`  bundles install runs successfully. Can anyone tell me why bundle install is not working. I tried updating bundler , didnt help.

And while trying I understand that for some reason fetching spree from github is not working but fetching other gems from github works

Comment: Does installing *anything* from GitHub work? Maybe your `git` connection is firewalled. Tried `https`?

Comment: There is no firewall blocking but how do you make it ` https ` . I tried ` git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com ` but it didnt change ` git://github.com/spree/spree.git ` to https.

Comment: Have you tried this on other computers? It does seem odd it's not working for you, but you'll need to try and isolate the problem systematically.

Comment: I there anyway I can do some debuggin on this?

Answer (score 1):

please check whether the branch you have mentioned in your Gemfile is available.

I believe branch `3.1.0` is still not available at spree repo at github.

current and stable branch is '3-0-stable'.

Comment: Ya. I was thinking about that too.. But I found same issue which was sorted out with this gem specification. https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_static_content/issues/189

Comment: And ` gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree' `
also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

When you're installing gems with `git`, or `github`, you have to make sure that the `tag`, `branch`, or `ref` you're referring to exists (bundler will just checkout the specified tag/branch/ref from the repository). Take a look at the available branches [here](https://github.com/spree/spree) and choose what to install: